# Getting an imscollpanel as a subplot along with another image

Tags: matlab, view, scroll, subplot

I a trying to generate a view in which I have an image on the top, and below I have a set of images, which are horizontally scrollable.

For displaying the set of images, I concatenate them into a single image horizontally and then display it.

I am able to display both of these figures separately, but when I try to merge them into a single figure(which has one figure on top and a scrollable view at the bottom), this code does not do the job. Instead, it just gives me the top figure(as I want) and the bottom image(without the scrollbar, which is not what I want). How do I get the scrollbar into the bottom image?

Here is what I tried(test3.png is what I want to display at the top and the images array is what I want at the bottom with a horizontal scroll):

```
hFig = figure('Toolbar','none','Menubar','none');
images{1} = imread('test1.png');
images{2} = imread('test2.png');
images{3} = imread('test1.png');
images{4} = imread('test2.png');
images{5} = imread('test1.png');
images{6} = imread('test2.png');
images{7} = imread('test1.png');
images{8} = imread('test2.png');
im = cat(2,images{:});
hIm = imshow(im);
hSP = imscrollpanel(hFig,hIm);

newFig = figure;
newhIm = imshow('test3.png');

figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
imshow('test3.png')
subplot(2,1,2);
imshow(getimage(hSP))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. The trick is based from [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101759-how-do-i-change-the-image-in-my-gui-by-targeting-an-axis-when-using-imscrollpanel-function-in-image) answer and consists in creating a `uipanel` in which to add an axes where you can create the `scrollpanel`.

Adapted for your scenario, here is how it looks like:

```
clear
clc

%// Read demo images and create cell array.
a = imread('peppers.png');
a1 = a(:,:,1);
b = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));

images{1} = a1;
images{2} = b;
images{3} = a1;
images{4} = b;
images{5} = a1;
images{6} = b;
images{7} = a1;
images{8} = b;
im = cat(2,images{:});

hf=figure; 

%// 1st subplot
hs1 = subplot(2,1,1);
imshow(a);

%// Create uipanel and place it below current image/subplot 1

hPanel= uipanel('Units','Normalized');

% Set the uipanel position to where the image is desired to be displayed.

set(hPanel,'position',[.05 0 .9 .5]);

%// Create an axes whose parent is the uipanel.
ax1 = axes('parent',hPanel,'position',[0 0 1 1],'Units','normalized');

%// Display image to get the handle.
him1 = imshow(im,'parent',ax1);

% Create the scroll panel
hSP = imscrollpanel(hPanel,him1);
```

Output:

[image]

You can fine-tune the position of the axes...but that should get you started. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like "add scrollbar to axis" to make it work with `subplot`. Hope [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14984-scrollplot-scrollable-x-y-axes) helps ...